# Gödel's result about induction

Tags: logic, reference-request, first-order-logic

In *Artificial Intelligence: A Modern Approach* there is a brief review of the history of logic, with a mention to Gödel's work.

It says:

> 1. In 1930, Kurt Gödel showed that there exists an effective procedure to prove any true statement in the first-order logic of Frege and Russell,
> 2. but that first-order logic could not capture the principle if mathematical induction needed to characterize the natural numbers.
> 3. In 1931, [...] his **Incompleteness Theorem** showed that limits on deduction do exist.

In *1.* the authors reference Gödel's Completeness Theorem for first order logic, but what is the result they are alluding to in *2.*?

Certainly not Incompleteness, since that is mentioned in 3 as a posterior result. What am I missing?

Comment: Not familiar with the work of Gödel sufficiently to point to a specific reference, but it follows directly from combining the completeness theorem with the incompleteness theorem.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft Which is the formal statement of the result you say that follows?

Comment: Since first order logic is complete, but no "nice enough" (not going to write out the formal part here) theory that contains the natural numbers can be complete, this shows the claim.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft That is Incompleteness. It is worth mentioning that right next to this they mention Incompleteness as a separate result, so it cannot be that.

Comment: It is not just incompleteness. It is the combination of the two.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft I fail to see how the claim that any axiomatizable, consistent formal theory extending arithmetic is incomplete is different from the Incompleteness Theorem

Comment: You also need the completeness theorem theorem  in order to conclude that this means first order logic cannot give you induction.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft What does it mean "first order logic cannot give you induction"?

Comment: It means that no first order theory can model the natural numbers (and specifically the induction is what causes the problems).

Comment: A little idea has occurred to me. Compactness can be used to show that even the non-axiomatizable theory of True Arithmetic has non-standard models. Maybe this is the result they are alluding to?

Comment: See this [post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1280438/non-standard-model-of-arithmetic-and-g%C3%B6dels-theorem): the result 2 was due to Skolem (1933). It can be "easily" derived by  juxtaposing Gödel's completeness theorem 1930  [point 1] and his incompleteness theorem 1931 [point 3], but this "easy" fact was explicitly recorded only in 1952.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Thanks for the reference. Note however that the result that follows from compactness is stronger, because it says that no theory of arithmetic is denumerable categorical, while the one that follows from Incompleteness is restricted to axiomatizable theories.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See Kurt Gödel (1934c), [Review of Skolem, *On the impossibility of a complete
characterization of the number sequence by means of a finite axiom system* (1933)](https://books.google.it/books?id=5E1KjgEACAAJ&pg=PA376); reprinted into Kurt Gödel, *Collected Works*, Vol.I (1986), page 379:

> The author [Skolem] proves that there is a system $N^*$ of entities, with two
>   operations, $+$ and $-$, defined on it and with two relations, $>$ and $=$, that
>   is not isomorphic to the system $N$ of natural numbers, but for which nevertheless all statements hold that are expressible by means of the symbols
>   mentioned at the outset and hold for the system $N$. From this it follows
>   that there is no axiom system [which presumably means no recursive (or possibly primitive recursive) set of axioms; from the *introductory Note* by Robert Vaught] employing only the notions mentioned at the outset (and therefore none at all employing only number-theoretic notions) that uniquely determines the structure of the sequence of natural numbers, a result that also follows without difficulty from the investigations of the reviewer [Kurt Gödel himself] in his 1931 [Über formal unentscheidbare Sätze der *Principia mathematica* und verwandter Systeme I].

From the *Introductory note*:

> Gödel remarks that this consequence of [Skolem's result *(1)*: "there exists a structure $\mathfrak N^*$ not isomorphic to $\mathfrak N$ which has the same
>   true (first-order) sentences as $\mathfrak N$"] follows from his 1931 *incompleteness theorem*. Indeed, if $\Sigma$ is any, say, recursive, set of sentences true in $\mathfrak N$, the incompleteness theorem tells us there is even a model $\mathfrak N'$ of $\Sigma$ in which some sentence true in $\mathfrak N$ is false. (As Kleene [*Introduction to metamathematics*, 1952, page 430] notes, this argument in fact also uses Gödel's *completeness theorem* from 1930.)
>
> However, the main result of Skolem's paper (as Skolem and Gödel both say) is certainly *(1)*, that the set of all true sentences in $\mathfrak N$ does not
>   characterize $\mathfrak N$. And the strange fact is that nowadays *(1)* is proved in a few lines by a "compactness argument", that is, from Gödel's compactness theorem (1930). [...]
>
> Thus it seems extraordinary that Skolem and especially Gödel himself did not observe that *(1)* is a simple consequence of the compactness theorem. Nevertheless, it appears that the idea of such simple (but important) applications of the compactness theorem was probably unknown before 1936 — in particular to Gödel and Skolem, and also to Tarski. [...] It appears that A.Maltsev, in 1936 and 1941, was the first person to publish such applications to algebra via "compactness arguments". [...] By 1941, Maltsev was making some quite sophisticated compactness arguments. But it was only after the Second World War that other logicians began to exploit the compactness theorem.

__

In conclusion, result 2. can be credited to Gödel (1931) with insight.

Answer (score 0):

One result they might be referring to is the [Compactness Theorem of FOL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compactness_theorem), since it implies that every first order theory of arithmetic has models which are not isomorphic to True Arithmetic.

The timelines coincide indeed, as Wikipedia says that Gödel first proved the result for countable theories in 1930.